# Export interactive grid to excel in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to export the Interactive Grid data into an excel. How can I do that. In the download option in Actions tab, it only has csv and HTML option. 
Can we add an option there to download the report in excel. Or can we add a button separtely, on click of which the report can be downloaded in xls.

Thanks,
Abha

Answer (score 1):

CSV **is** Excel. Not a *true* MS Excel file (i.e. XLS or XLSX), but - Excel opens a **C**omma-**S**eparated-**V**alues file without any problems.

So - export as CSV, open with Excel. Should be just fine.

Comment: Yes, I can open the csv as excel , if we open it with "open with excel" option. I am actually looking for a option where just by clicking on the file it opens in excel. I have actually figured out a solution by using a plugin : http://glebovpavel.github.io/Description_IR_TO_XSLX/ . This looks to work fine.

Comment: "Excel opens a csv file without any problems." I disagree - Excel does strange things to .csv files (tries to interpret numbers like 12.39 as dates (December '39). A native Excel Export option like xls or xlsx is much more robust IME.

Comment: I'm afraid you're right, @Frank - thank you for comment. Though, there are ways (https://www.exceldemy.com/how-to-stop-excel-from-changing-numbers-to-dates/) to *fool* Excel from being a fool. Some of these can be applied to CSV files so ... it is good we have workaround(s).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, interactive reports and grids support exporting to native Excel (xlsx), as well as Word (rtf) and PDF.

To enable this there are multiple options:

- Oracle BI Publisher
- FOP (ORDS)
- APEX Office Print (AOP)

Once you have configured the print server (this is an APEX instance-wide setting), you can then enable the output options in your IR or IG regions.

https://insum.ca/oracle-apex-printing-options/
*(note: I'm not sure that all the other printing options mentioned in this link support interactive reports or grids)*

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. although I have found a nice plugin that can be used to directly download the interactive grid as xlsx. http://glebovpavel.github.io/Description_IR_TO_XSLX/. But i will surely go thruogh the links that u have provided. Thanks